# How to display video and capture image into two thread by PyQt5?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5

I am creating a tool for showing webcam and displaying image captured into label in PyQt5. So I have created 2 thread in my code below. One is to show webcam, one is to capture and detect image.

Problem: First, I click "camera button" to display webcam. Then when I click "capture button" to capture current image and detect this, webcam's thread is frozen.

I don't know how to solving this problem.
How can I fix it ?

**File main.py**

```
import sys
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time

from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, Qt, QThread, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from capture import Ui_MainWindow
from ultralytics import YOLO

model = YOLO("last.pt")

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    # signal = pyqtSignal(np.ndarray)
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.uic = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.uic.setupUi(self)

        self.uic.camera.clicked.connect(self.show_camera)
        self.uic.capture.clicked.connect(self.capture)

        self.thread = {}

    def show_camera(self):
        self.thread[1] = capture_video(index=1)
        self.thread[1].start()
        self.thread[1].signal.connect(self.show_wedcam)

    def capture(self):

        self.thread[2] = capture_image(index=2)
        self.thread[2].start()
        self.thread[2].signal.connect(self.show_image)

    def show_image(self, cv_img):
        qt_img = convert_cv_qt(cv_img)
        self.uic.screen_cap.setPixmap(qt_img)
    def show_wedcam(self, cv_img):
        """Updates the image_label with a new opencv image"""
        index = self.sender().index
        qt_img = convert_cv_qt(cv_img)
        self.uic.screen_cam.setPixmap(qt_img)

def convert_cv_qt(cv_img):
    """Convert from an opencv image to QPixmap"""
    rgb_image = cv2.cvtColor(cv_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    h, w, ch = rgb_image.shape
    bytes_per_line = ch * w
    convert_to_Qt_format = QtGui.QImage(rgb_image.data, w, h, bytes_per_line, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)
    # p = convert_to_Qt_format.scaled(1024, 980, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
    return QPixmap.fromImage(convert_to_Qt_format)

class capture_video(QThread):
    signal = pyqtSignal(np.ndarray)
    def __init__(self, index):
        self.index = index
        print("start threading", self.index)
        super(capture_video, self).__init__()
        self.is_running = True

    def run(self):
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        frame_count = 0
        start_time = time.time()
        while cap.isOpened():
            # Read a frame from the video
            success, frame = cap.read()
            if not success:
                break
            frame_count += 1
            elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
            fps = frame_count / elapsed_time
            frame_text = cv2.putText(frame, f'FPS: {round(fps, 2)}', (50, 80), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 3, (255, 0, 0), 2)
            self.signal.emit(frame_text)
            cv2.waitKey(1)
        cap.release()

    def stop(self):
        if self.is_running:
            self.is_running = False
            print("Stop thread ...", self.index)
            self.quit()
class capture_image(QThread):
    signal = pyqtSignal(np.ndarray)
    def __init__(self, index):
        self.index = index
        print("start threading", self.index)
        super(capture_image, self).__init__()
        self.is_running = True
    def run(self):
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        while cap.isOpened() and self.is_running:
            # Read a frame from the video
            success, frame = cap.read()
            if not success:
                break
            results = model(frame)
            frame_det = results[0].plot()
            self.signal.emit(frame_det)
            self.is_running = False
        cap.release()
    def stop(self):
        if self.is_running:
            self.is_running = False
            print("Stop thread ...", self.index)
            self.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_win = MainWindow()
    main_win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

**File capture.py**

````
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(651, 515)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.camera = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.camera.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 100, 81, 41))
        self.camera.setObjectName("camera")
        self.capture = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.capture.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 300, 111, 41))
        self.capture.setObjectName("capture")
        self.screen_cam = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.screen_cam.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 20, 491, 201))
        self.screen_cam.setScaledContents(True)
        self.screen_cam.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.screen_cam.setObjectName("screen_cam")
        self.screen_cap = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.screen_cap.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 240, 491, 221))
        self.screen_cap.setScaledContents(True)
        self.screen_cap.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.screen_cap.setObjectName("screen_cap")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 651, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.camera.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Camera"))
        self.capture.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Capture and Detect"))
        self.screen_cam.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.screen_cap.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))```
````

Comment: What do you mean by "webcam's thread doesn't work"? Isn't it possible that, in fact, the whole program is frozen? Try to press buttons again and see if they "push", because I believe that the issue is that you're trying to open the same capture device twice (which I don't think it's possible, but I'm not sure about it). Try to run your program in a terminal or prompt and see if you get any error output there. Note that if you just want to capture the *current frame* while playing video, trying to open the device again is pointless, just "save" the current frame received from the video stream.

Comment: Yes, camera's screen is frozen. I want to detect image real time, so I think saving image will make my program become slower.

Comment: You don't need to physically *save* the image to disk, just store a reference to it.